# How can I make double box-shadow on an element in CSS?

Tags: button, css

How can I make both inner shadow (top) and outer shadow on an element in CSS?

The button Facebook uses in their mobile application, has both:

- Slight white line at the top of the button,
- And a slight white line at the bottom of the button.
- With a solid border

[image: Standard button on the Facebook IOS mobile application]

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 `box-shadow` to get the effect you want. a simple example

```
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #666;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #666;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #666;
```

furthermore you can specify `inset` property in order to get inner glow.

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #666;
```

There is a comprehensive reference on this in [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/box-shadow)